# monitor progress of command line operations

Tags: mysql, windows, cmd

I am trying to do a `mysqldump` using `cmd.exe` on a windows 7 machine.  The database might be 100 GB in size, so the `mysqldump` might take a long time.  But how do I check to make sure that it is actually working?

Here is a print screen of the command prompt:

[image]

Notice that it is just hung up, like it might be if it were in the middle of running a program.  It has been this way for 20 minutes.  The `all_databases.sql` file has indeed been created on my machine by the above commands, but it remains empty.  Is there some other way to monitor progress besides the size of the `all_databases.sql` output file?  If this command is going to take 24 to 36+ hours to run, I would like to have confidence that it is actually running all the time.  I would be disappointed to discover in 2 days that it had not done anything.

I am using MySQL 5.6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a way to have mysqldump progress bar which shows the users the status of their backups?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852933/is-there-a-way-to-have-mysqldump-progress-bar-which-shows-the-users-the-status-o)

Comment: There appears to be a command-line option: `--show-progress-size`

Comment: @Gerrat Would my code need to change?  If so, what specifically should my command line code be?  The link you sent said that `--show-progress-size` defaults to 10,000.

Comment: @Gerrat The command has been running for 40 minutes now with no progress update.  Also, if I kill the instance of `cmd.exe` and start over with a new instance and a new command, how can I make sure that I have not done any damage by stopping and restarting?  Thank you.

Comment: Well, you're dumping `from` a database, so it shouldn't do any damage `to` the database (but the all_databases.sql file will likely be useless).  It looks like the option may actually be called `--verbose`, but I've never used it, so I can't say for sure.

Comment: You may also just be able to open another command prompt and periodically look at the size of the all_databases.sql file.  It should be growing over time if the process is working.

Answer (score 1):

The best and simple way is to open another command line and check the processlist in the mysql server.

Secondly you can check whether the size of dump increases or not..

Thanks