# is there a way to have mysqldump progress bar which shows the users the status of their backups?

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, mariadb

i'm developing an app for my company, using Python2.7 and MariaDB. I have created a functions which backups our main database server to another database server. I use this command to do it:`mysqldump -h localhost -P 3306 -u root -p mydb | mysql -h bckpIPsrv -P 3306 -u root -p mydb2` .
  I want to know if it's posible to see some kind of verbose mode or a percentage of the job and display it on screen.

thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a way to have mysqldump progress bar which shows the users the status of their backups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852933/is-there-a-way-to-have-mysqldump-progress-bar-which-shows-the-users-the-status-o)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try referring to this: [is there a way to have mysqldump progress bar which shows the users the status of their backups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852933/is-there-a-way-to-have-mysqldump-progress-bar-which-shows-the-users-the-status-o) and making changes to your command, passing in the parameters `--show-progress-size` and `--verbose`

Comment: Have you ever tried this? The progress-size patch doesn't appear in the product.

Answer (score -1):

dumpcmd = "mysqldump -h " + DB_HOST + " -u " + DB_USER + " -p" + DB_USER_PASSWORD + " " + DB_NAME + "| pv | gzip > " + pipes.quote(
    BACKUP_PATH) + "/" + FILE_NAME + ".sql"

Comment: Please try formatting your answer and give reason as to why this code would help solve OP's answer.