# mysqlpump without database prefix

Tags: mysql

The tool `mysqlpump` prepends every table action with the database name like so:

```
INSERT INTO `database`.`table` --
```

This makes the export rather limited in use. **Is there a way to skip the database prefix?** It would make sense, as I'm observing the many situations in which it is a limitation rather than a feature.

#### Attempted workarounds:

Not having figured out a sane way to do this, I've tried a dirty `sed` hack on the export:

```
sed -e "s/\`$DB\`.//g"
```

This works nicely on small exports. However, on more complex databases, this will eventually cause errors. Apparently the back-ticked database cannot be reliably used as a string used exclusively as a statement prefix.

#### See also:

- [`mysqlpump` options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlpump.html#mysqlpump-option-summary)

Comment: Great question. Did you figure out how to better handle this?

Comment: Unfortunately not @Wouter, but I only looked for a couple of years. I phased out my work with MySQL. At the time I usually did a `sed` pass as described and then a manual search for any references to `$DB` without the backticks.

Answer (score -1):

which options do you use for `mysqldump`? By default, there's no database name prefix before the table name.
  E.g. `mysqldump -uxx -pxxx -h xxx -P xxx --all-databases > db.sql`
  `mysqldump -uxx -pxxx -h xxx -P xxx db table > table.sql`

Comment: I'm not using `mysqldump`. I'm using the new and improved `mysqlpump`. I think you accidentally read __d__ in stead of __p__.

Comment: @Redsandro sorry, my bad, actually so far `mysqlpump` is not recommened, for example, it's not safe if you are using GTID, it's not consistent dump(no lock, no transaction). If you want to use parallel dump, suggest you use `mydumper`, I hope in the future they will improve `mysqlpump`