# Visually update size of file during mysql dump via tunnel

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh

I have a bash script called `copydata` which does the following to do a MySQL dump of specific tables from our production MySQL server to a local file, and then push it into my local MySQL database.

```
#!/bin/sh
#set up tunnel
ssh -f -i ~/.ssh/ec2-eu-keypair.pem -o CompressionLevel=9 -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -L 3307:elr2.our-id.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306 username@example.com

echo "Dumping tables \"$@\" to /tmp/data.sql"
#dump tables to local file
mysqldump -u root -h 127.0.0.1 -pmypass  -P 3307 live_db_name  --extended-insert --single-transaction --default-character-set=utf8 --skip-set-charset $@ > /tmp/data.sql
pv /tmp/data.sql | mysql -u root local_db_name --default-character-set=utf8 --binary-mode --force
```

So, it is called like `copydata table1 table2`

It works, but the `mysqldump` part can take a very long time, and it would be nice to have some visual feedback on progress.   One thing which occurred to me is that I could show the size of `/tmp/data.sql` while the dump is in progress - if I just keep doing the following, in a seperate tab, for example, I can see it going up at the rate of approx 2mb per second:

```
ls -lh /tmp/data.sql
```

Can I add the above command, or something similar, to the above script so that I can see the file size updating while i'm waiting for the mysqldump line to complete?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does mysqldump support a progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852933/does-mysqldump-support-a-progress-bar)

Comment: In bash you can try:  `mysqldump ... > /tmp/data.sql &`, then `pid=$! ; while [ -d "/proc/$pid" ] ; do ls -l /tmp/data.sql; sleep 1; done`

Comment: @alecxs the version we use doesn't have that option unfortunately.  Sorry, i should have put the mysql version in the question.

Comment: @YuriLachin thanks - that did it!  I tweaked it a bit to to keep the output on a single line, so it updates in place.  `pid=$!; while [ -d "/proc/$pid" ] ; do  echo -n "$(ls -lh /tmp/data.sql)"\\r; sleep 0.5; done`

Comment: `pv` isn't related to mysql

Comment: @alecxs oh, wait, you meant the second answer not the correct one, right?  The problem with that one is that you have to tell pv the size of the file, so it can calculate the percentage, and I don't know what that will be in this case - it can vary by several orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @YuriLachin in the comments, I did the following:

1. added a `&` to the mysqldump line, so it becomes asynchronous, ie the script carries on to the next line while the mysqldump continues in the background
2. added this line, to repeatedly call `ls -lh` on the local file:

```
pid=$!; while [ -d "/proc/$pid" ] ; do  echo -n "$(ls -lh /tmp/data.sql)"\\r; sleep 1; done
```

Lets break that down, to aid my own learning as much as anything else:

```
#get the process id of that last backgrounded task (the mysqldump) so we
#can tell when it's finished running
pid=$!
#while it *is* still running
while [ -d "/proc/$pid" ] ; do
  #get the size of the file, with ls, but do it inside an echo command.  
  #Wrapping it like this allows us to use the `-n` option which means "omit newline", 
  #or don't go onto the next line.  Then, at the end, do \\r which is a carriage return, 
  #meaning 'go back to the start of the current line', so the next line will 
  #overwrite the first one.
  #Now it updates in place rather than spewing out loads of lines.
  echo -n "$(ls -lh /tmp/data.sql)"\\r
  #then do nothing for 1 second, to avoid wasting cpu time.
  sleep 1
done
```